Unable to setup a NextJS project using Deno 2
I'm trying to setup a NextJS project based on Deno2 using the following Deno 2 docs.
Deno2 NextJS
However, I get Hydration Failed error once I run the code. Steps to reproduce -
deno run -A npm:create-next-app@latest
deno install
deno task dev

I followed the advice from Github Discussions to rm -rf node_modules and .next but to no avail.

So, apparently, it works with Next14 but not 15!
deno run -A npm:create-next-app@14 -- This works!
deno run -A npm:create-next-app@latest -- This doesn't!


Deno 2.1.0 was release 12 hour ago. Update Deno using deno upgrade and try again. I couldn't reproduce your issue on the version 2.1.0.

In my case, I've encounted "next: command not found".
To resolve this error, I run:
deno install npm:next

